Do different fields need to have some properties that differ from each other?
I am reading Introduction to Real Analysis by Robert G Bartle, and while reading it I was quite confused at the property of Completeness of real numbers.
The author introduces the fields Q and R and compares them by saying that they both are fields and both of them are ordered, but √2 belongs in R but not Q, so there must be an additional property to "characterize" R, from where they introduced the Completeness property.
I don't seem to understand how the author makes this claim. Must all distinct fields have some properties that make them differ from each other? Consider the field consisting of the usual addition and multiplication with the set S = {a + b√2: a,b ∈ Q}. This set differs from Q yet is not complete (one can make an infinite set of the decimal approximations of π, making π the supremum of such a set, yet it doesn't belong to S), so must this have set S some other property to "characterize" it?
Is it not possible for two fields to have different elements and yet be the "same" in the sense that they have the exact same set of properties?

also $\sqrt2\in \mathbb S$ but $\sqrt2\not\in\mathbb Q$

@J.W.Tanner Yes, that is what I meant to say by the set "differs" from Q.

Not sure what you are asking.  If two fields are non-isomorphic then there is clearly something that distinguishes them.  Is that what you are asking?

@Julu What is meant by two fields being non-isomorphic?

Of course there are isomorphic fields that "look different" in some sense.  For instance, if $\alpha$ denotes a root of $x^3-2$, then $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is a well defined field and choosing two different roots just leads to isomorphic fields.

Given two fields, $F_1, F_2$, we can speak of homomorphisms $\phi: F_1\to F_1$ that preserve the field structure.  So $\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$ and $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$.  One of these is an isomorphism if the function $\phi$ is a bijection of sets.  For instance, complex conjugation is an isomorphism from $\mathbb C$ to itself.

If there is nothing which distinguishes $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{R}$, then are they not the same field? (up to isomorphism, I suppose...)

See Sec. 2.3 paragraph 1 here for the original wording: "This observation shows the necessity of an additional property to characterize the real number system."

The discussion about $\sqrt{2}$ already gives one property that distinguishes the fields $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$: the equation $x^2=2$ has a solution in $\mathbb R$, but that same equation has no solution in $\mathbb Q$.
But that is a rather weak property. For example, although that property distinguishes $\mathbb R$ from $\mathbb Q$, it does not distinguish $\mathbb R$ from the other field that you mentioned, namely $S$ also known as $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}] = \{a+b\sqrt{2} \mid a,b \in \mathbb Q\}$.
The purpose of the completeness property is to give a much stronger property that distinguishes $\mathbb R$ from many, many other sorts of fields that one might imagine.

To address your question in the comments, an isomorphism between two fields $\mathbb E$ and $\mathbb F$ is a bijection $f : \mathbb E \to \mathbb F$ which "preserves* all of the algebraic operations. Thus, for example, $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$, and $f(a \cdot b) = f(a) \cdot f(b)$, and $f(-a)=-f(a)$, and $f(1/a)=1/f(a)$ (if $a \ne 0$), and so on. To say that two fields are isomorphic means that there exists an isomorphism between them. One way to prove that two fields are not isomorphic is to write down some property, to prove that two isomorphic fields must share that property (meaning it is either true in both or false in both), and then to prove that this property is true for one of the fields and false for the other. One such property, relevant to your post, is whether the equation $x^2=2$ has a solution in the field.

Finally, you ask whether all distinct fields must have some property that distinguishes between them. To put this another way, if two fields are not isomorphic, is there a property that is true in one of those two fields and false in the other? This, as it turns out, is a rather delicate question of logic; you might gain some insight from this MO post. I won't attempt to answer it in the generality in which you posed the question, but I will discuss some cases relevant to your post.
In the case of the field $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$, one can list properties that distinguish it from all other fields up to isomorphism: it is a degree $2$ extension of $\mathbb Q$ (i.e. it is a 2-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb Q$); and the equation $x^2=2$ has a solution in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$. Every field that satisfies these two properties is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$. In fact every field $\mathbb F$ which is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Q$ can be similarly characterized, using properties that are expressed in terms of appropriate polynomials with integer coefficients that have roots in $\mathbb F$; these are known as the number fields over $\mathbb Q$, and they are the subjects of algebraic number theory.
And in the case of the real numbers $\mathbb R$, there is a very nice theorem: Every complete ordered field is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ (if you are working in 2nd order logic).

I understood that to truly understand the 2nd and 3rd parts of your answer, I must learn more. Which branches of mathematics do Isomorphism and 2nd order logic fall under?

Isomorphism is a concept common across all of mathematics. In the context of your present post, you will run across it in a class or book on abstract algebra. Every different category of mathematical objects has its own special notion of isomorphism: you can have isomorphic groups, isomorphic fields, isomorphic vector spaces, and so on and so on.

Regarding 2nd order logic, that's just a fancy way of saying that one is allowed to quantify across all sets. I suggest simply looking closely at the proof linked in my last paragraph.

You should look up the construction of the real numbers through Dedekind cuts. As it turns out, you can extract the real numbers from the rationals by looking at all "cuts" of the rational number line. The completeness property, in such a context, says that if you perform the same operation on the real number line, you do not get a new structure, rather you get the real numbers again, so they are, sort of, complete.
